# TypeError: Cannot read property 'markets' of undefined (line 23)

Tags: mongodb, api, google-apps-script

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'markets' of undefined (line 23)

I use the same database without touching anything for 6 months, it had never failed, today this error started to appear and I've tried to find the fault but I'm not able to find the fault when collecting the data.

Here is the basis from which I collect the values (you can access the data map by clicking on the link):
https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/oddsbf-dvyne/service/http/incoming_webhook/webhook0

Here is the script I use:

```
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/oddsbf-dvyne/service/http/incoming_webhook/webhook0");
  const mongo_matches = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  const matches = mongo_matches.map(function(match) {
    var over = '-'
    var under = '-'
    if(match['markets']['over_25'] !== undefined && 
       match['markets']['over_25']['over']['odds'] !== undefined && 
       (match['markets']['over_25']['over']['odds']['availableToBack'].length > 0 &&
         match['markets']['over_25']['under']['odds']['availableToBack'].length > 0 )){
      over = match['markets']['over_25']['over']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['over_25']['over']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['markets']['over_25']['over']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble']
      under = match['markets']['over_25']['under']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['over_25']['under']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['markets']['over_25']['under']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble']
    }
    return [
      match['markets']['marketStartTime'],
      match['markets']['lastSaved'],
      match['markets']['competition'],
      match['markets']['homeTeam']['runnerName'],
      match['markets']['awayTeam']['runnerName'],
      match['markets']['homeTeam']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['homeTeam']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['markets']['homeTeam']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'],
        match['markets']['awayTeam']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['awayTeam']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['markets']['awayTeam']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'],
          match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['draw']['markets']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'],
            under,
              over,
                ]; 
  });
```

Line 23 that is giving the error is this one:

```
          match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['draw']['markets']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line 23 with this:

```
match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0] !== undefined ? match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToBack'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'] : match['markets']['draw']['odds']['availableToLay'][0]['price']['$numberDouble'],
```

---

**Update:**

```
Logger.log(mongo_matches['draw'])
Logger.log(mongo_matches['matches'])
```

both return null. Meaning that you can't access an information from a null object.

Comment: Mate... I did the test as you indicated and it returned to work perfectly!